# App is sending an email to the wrong person, anyone knows why or how to resolve?

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I am still having some issues with the issue I posted last time regardin formview not updating correctly.

I have managed to narraow the problem to one sub below:

My issue *appears* to be on this line:

```
tbl.Rows.AddAt(tbl.Rows.Count - 1, row)
```

Anytime I attempt to update a row, only the first row gets updated. Subsequent rows don't get updated. Instead, when I click "Update", the cursor moves down to the next record without updating it.

When I commented out this

`tbl.Rows.AddAt(tbl.Rows.Count - 1, row)`, I can now update each and every row.

After updating the row, an email goes out to the individual advising him/her about the update s/he just made. The problem is that email is getting sent to the wrong person and that's because of that one line that I just commented out.

Answer (score 0):

When you are updating via `tbl.Rows.AddAt`, you are only updating the grid HTML, not the database. You need to make your changes to the underlying data source which is bound to the grid, and then possibly will need to re-DataBind the grid so that it sees the updated data source.

Comment: Thank you sir for your kind and prompt response. Do you mind giving me an example, please?

Comment: I don't have time, and besides, you haven't shown us what you're using as a data source for your grid. Basically, forget about changing the grid - you need to change the data.